# Проблема с добавлением своей функции в модель product OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, функции

Добавляю функцию в модель `product`. Вызываю её и получаю такое: 
`Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getHomeProduct in catalog/controller/extension/module/home_banner.php on line 12`

Что может быть не так?

сама функция:

```
public function getHomeProduct() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ".DB_PREFIX."_product.product_id, ".DB_PREFIX."_product.image AS title, ".DB_PREFIX."_product_image.image, ".DB_PREFIX."_product_description.name FROM ".DB_PREFIX."_product LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."_product_description ON ".DB_PREFIX."_product_description.product_id = ".DB_PREFIX."_product.product_id LEFT JOIN oc_product_image ON ".DB_PREFIX."_product_image.product_id = ".DB_PREFIX."_product.product_id WHERE ".DB_PREFIX."_product.for_home = 1");

    print_r($query);

    return $query->rows;

}
```

Comment: что находится на 12 строке?

Comment: Вот тут решение твоей проблемы
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512173/error-refering-to-this-from-a-tpl-file-in-opencart-2-0-3-1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171267/opencart-2-0-get-config-value-from-admin-or-frontend-also-permission

Comment: @mydls1 вообще другая проблема

Comment: Методы другие, ошибка подобная.

Answer (score 0):

Неопределенное свойство `Proxy::getHomeProduct`.
Проверьте это свойство, есть ли оно и является ли статическим

Comment: я добавил функцию по аналогии с остальными. добавил в шапку функцию.

Comment: `public **static** function getHomeProduct()`
Пропишите static, так как вы таким образом  `Proxy::getHomeProduct`  вызываете статический метод

Comment: Прописал - ошибка есть. 

вот так вызываю функцию:
`  $this->load->model('catalog/product');

  $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getHomeProduct();`

Comment: упс, `static` без звездочек естественно `public static function getHomeProduct()`

Comment: так без них и добавил.

Comment: Уточним:
1. `model_catalog_product` - эта переменная содержит экземпляр продукта?
2. функция `getHomeProduct()` у вас находится в классе продукт?
3. при таком вызове `$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getHomeProduct();` функция не должна иметь `static`

Comment: В данном случае у вас получается вызов функции из переменной `model_catalog_product`, если она не содержит экземпляр продукта, то получается что вы пытаетесь из неё вызвать метод гет, который находится в классе `product` отсюда и ошибка